# Finding equation of ellipse with given point and distance between directrices

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I need to find the equation of an ellipse. The given were just a point where it passes, and distance between directrices.

I know that the distance between directrices is given by $2a/e$. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You don't have enough information to fully define the ellipse; not even close.

Answer (score 0):

Use $d(P, F)=ed(P, \mathcal{D})$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is $\{x=\dfrac{a^2}{c}\}$, $P=(x, y)$ and $F=(c, 0)$.